# How to implement Miracast in my android app

Tags: android

I am trying to find details on how to implement screencasting via Miracast in my application.  The only details I can find are part of the AllshareCast SDK from Samsung, which is not the same standard as (although very similar to) Miracast.

Can someone please point me in the direction of how I could achieve a simple in application Miracast button (like the YouTube app for example)?

EDIT:  Improved question:

How can I share the application display to and external monitor or projector using wireless protocol such as Miracast.

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: Hey! found any solution? I'm also trying to cast my android application on a TV screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking "how do I arrange to show something different on an external display, like one connected via Miracast, than what is shown on the device's own screen", you will want to use the `Presentation` class, along with either `DisplayManager` or `MediaRouter`.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for the poorly worded question.  I will rephrase and see what I can find about DisplayManager and Presentation class.

Comment: @andy: Here is a presentation that I did earlier in 2013 on `Presentation`: http://www.slideshare.net/commonsguy/secondscreen-support-in-android-42

Comment: Thank you for the presentation!  I am just working through my options now.

Comment: Does `Presentation` class use `Wifi-Direct` or `Miracast` behind the scene ? Thanks :)

Comment: Did u got any solution?